# Is it possible for properties to return self-destruct objects

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

I would like to build subproperties and therefore have properties return objects.

```
TRoom=class (TObject)    
public
 Constructor create(AParent:TFlat;ID:String)
 property Enabled:boolean read GetEnabled write SetEnabled;
end

TFlat=class (TObject)
public
 property Room[Roomname:String]:TRoom read GetRoom;
end

procedure TRoom.SetEnabled(Value:Boolean);
begin
 //Do something
 Free; //Free my self
end;

function TRoom.GetEnabled:Boolean;
begin
 Result:=TRUE; //something
 Free; //Free my self so we have no memory leak
end;

function TFlat.GetRoom(Roomname:String):TRoom;    
begin
 Result:=TRoom.Create(Self,Roomname); //Create and return the room object
end
```

Leading up to a code that would call a TFlat object like this

```
Flat:=TFlat.Create;
Flat.Room['Bedroom'].Enabled:=TRUE;
```

Is this possible/feasable?
EDIT1: The getter and Setter methods would talk to a WebAPI and actually do stuff. The object itself will not need to remember anything.
EDIT2: My Goal is to be able to write code like

```
Room['Bedroom'].Temperatur:=23;
If Room['Office'].Enabled then Room['Office'].Lights.Scene='gaming';
```

Comment: You could use some managed type like `record`, `interface` or `Variant`. You shouldn't free `TRoom` instance in getter or setter of its property. Think of what happens when you assign the instance to a local varialble `var LRoom := Flat.Room['Bedroom'];`.

Comment: I don't understand the goal to set a Room.Enabled when the underlying TRoom is (going to be) destroyed? Seems you are using the wrong approach in the first place.

Comment: What do you men by **self-destruct** objects? What are you actually trying to achieve? Are you perhaps trying to design `Room` property of your `TFlat` class to return existing `TRoom` class instance if a room with specific name already exist and create a new one if it doesn't?

Comment: @SilverWarrior: Post updated, the Room is not perma-existing, it should only define the context for the following properties.

Comment: @UweRaabe: Post updated. The object doesnt store any values. It calls a webAPI to query or set those properties.

Comment: @PeterWolf I'll look into those other types except {record}, as those objects need to execute code. Only i am using that code, so using it in a local variable is not an issue.

Comment: Forget about these _self-destruct objects_ in favor of static instances owned by the container.

Comment: `If Room['Office'].Enabled then Room['Office'].Lights.Scene='gaming';` is calling `GetRoom()` twice, so would create 2 separate `TRoom` objects for the same room, is that what you really want? A better design is to have `TFlat` hold a list of `TRoom` objects, such as in a `TDictionary`, and then have `GetRoom()` simply return the appropriate `TRoom`, creating it only if it doesn't already exist. Be sure to destroy the objects in the `TFlat.Destroy()` destructor.

Comment: Records can have and execute code!